# The method '[]' was called on null.Realtime Database using Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

The way i inserted data into firebase realtime:

[image]

The code that procues this:

```
 void SaveRideRequest() {
    rideRequestReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Ride Requests").push();

    var pickUp = Provider
        .of<AppData>(context, listen: false)
        .pickUpLoacation;
    var dropOff = Provider
        .of<AppData>(context, listen: false)
        .dropOffLocation;

    Map pickUpLocationMap = {

      "latitude": pickUp.latitude.toString(),
      "longitude": pickUp.longitude.toString(),

    };

    Map dropOffUpLocationMap = {

      "latitude": dropOff.latitude.toString(),
      "longitude": dropOff.longitude.toString(),

    };

    Map riderInfoMap = {
      "driver_id:": "Waiting",
      "payment_method": "cash",
      "pickup": pickUpLocationMap,
      "dropOff": dropOffUpLocationMap,
      "created at": DateTime.now().toString(),
      "rider_name ": userCurrentInfo.name,
      "rider_phone ": userCurrentInfo.phone,
      "pickup_address": pickUp.placeName,
      "dropOff_address": dropOff.placeName,


    };

    rideRequestReference.set(riderInfoMap);
  }
```

I am trying to use to following code to retrieve data from firebase real time.

```
DatabaseReference newRequestRef=FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Ride Requests");
```

void retrieveRideRequestInfo(String rideRequestId) {

```
newRequestRef.child(rideRequestId).once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapShot) {

        double pickUpLocationLat=double.parse(dataSnapShot.value['pickup']['latitude']);
        double pickUpLocationLng=double.parse(dataSnapShot.value['pickup']['longitude']);
        String pickUpAddress=dataSnapShot.value['pickup_address'].toString();

        double dropOffLocationLat=double.parse(dataSnapShot.value['dropOff']['latitude:']);
        double dropOffLocationLng=double.parse(dataSnapShot.value['dropOff']['longitude']);
        String dropOffAddress=dataSnapShot.value['dropOff_address'].toString();

        String paymentMethod=dataSnapShot.value['payment_method'].toString();


        RideDetails rideDetails=RideDetails();

        rideDetails.ride_request_id=rideRequestId;
        rideDetails.pickup_address=pickUpAddress;
        rideDetails.pickup_address=dropOffAddress;
        rideDetails.pickup=LatLng(pickUpLocationLat, pickUpLocationLng);
        rideDetails.dropOff=LatLng(dropOffLocationLat,dropOffLocationLng);

        rideDetails.payment_method=paymentMethod;


        print("Information::");
        print(rideDetails.pickup_address);
        print(rideDetails.dropOff_address);    
    });
  }
}
```

However , I am getting the following error:

> E/flutter ( 8701): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
>
> E/flutter ( 8701): Receiver: null
>
> E/flutter ( 8701): Tried calling:

I can't find out where in the code i made mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple child nodes under `Ride Requests`. So when you use `newRequestRef.child(rideRequestId).once()`, your `dataSnapShot` contains the information for all of them.

When you access `dataSnapShot.value['pickup']`, there is no node `Ride Requests/pickup`, so it returns null. So when you then to `dataSnapShot.value['pickup']['latitude']`, you're calling `['latitude']` on null, which is what the error message says.

To solve this, you'll need to access the properties on the individual child nodes of `Ride Requests`. This use to be pretty tricky (see [here]), but now that this [feature request](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/753) has been implement, you should be able to loop over `dataSnapshot.value.values`.

So something like:

```
dataSnapshot.value.values.forEach((snapshot) => {
    double pickUpLocationLat=double.parse(snapshot.value['pickup']['latitude']);
    double pickUpLocationLng=double.parse(snapshot.value['pickup']['longitude']);
    ...
```